# Creating Custom SurfaceView like a layout. Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-custom-view, android-launcher

I am doing an Android project. In that I am creating a custom Launcher.

I have to load All applications and widgets installed on phone.

**My Problem:**

If I do long press on any of Icon from App list, that Icon should copy to the home screen and user can play with Icon by moving, just like creating shortcut (As we have this functionality of all Android devices).

How can I make a custom surface same like my home screen layout, as user can move Icon whole screen.?

When user removes his finger from Icon, it should place in those X and Y positions.

The Black color appearing on middle of layout in FIG 3 is a surfaceView.

**My Code:**

**MainActivity.java - FIG 1**

On Long press listener code:

```
hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hiddenPanel is appList panel.
        MainGamePanel mainpanel = new MainGamePanel(MainActivity.this, iconDrawable,xPosition,yPosition);
        middleLayout.addView(mainpanel); //"middleLayout" is a Relative layout
```

**MainGamePanel.java - FIG 3**

public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
private static final String TAG = MainGamePanel.class.getSimpleName();

private MainThread thread;
private Droid droid;
private Drawable drawableIcon;
private int xPosition;
private int yPostion;

public MainGamePanel(Context context, Drawable iconDrawable, int x, int y) {
    super(context);
    // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.drawableIcon = iconDrawable;
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableIcon).getBitmap();
    this.xPosition = x;
    this.yPostion = y;

    // create droid and load bitmap
    // droid = new Droid(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    // R.drawable.ic_launcher), 50, 50);
    droid = new Droid(bitmap, xPosition, yPostion);

    // create the game loop thread
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);

    // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    // at this point the surface is created and
    // we can safely start the game loop
    if (!thread.isAlive()) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Surface is being destroyed");
    // tell the thread to shut down and wait for it to finish
    // this is a clean shutdown
    boolean retry = true;
    while (retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // try again shutting down the thread
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Thread was shut down cleanly");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // delegating event handling to the droid
        droid.handleActionDown((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

        // check if in the lower part of the screen we exit
        if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 50) {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
        }
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // the gestures
        if (droid.isTouched()) {
            // the droid was picked up and is being dragged
            droid.setX((int) event.getX());
            droid.setY((int) event.getY());
        }
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // touch was released
        if (droid.isTouched()) {
            droid.setTouched(false);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    droid.draw(canvas);
}

/**
 * This is the game update method. It iterates through all the objects and
 * calls their update method if they have one or calls specific engine's
 * update method.
 */
public void update() {
    // check collision with right wall if heading right
    if (droid.getSpeed().getxDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_RIGHT
            && droid.getX() + droid.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2 >= getWidth()) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleXDirection();
    }
    // check collision with left wall if heading left
    if (droid.getSpeed().getxDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_LEFT
            && droid.getX() - droid.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2 <= 0) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleXDirection();
    }
    // check collision with bottom wall if heading down
    if (droid.getSpeed().getyDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_DOWN
            && droid.getY() + droid.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2 >= getHeight()) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleYDirection();
    }
    // check collision with top wall if heading up
    if (droid.getSpeed().getyDirection() == Speed.DIRECTION_UP
            && droid.getY() - droid.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2 <= 0) {
        droid.getSpeed().toggleYDirection();
    }
    // Update the lone droid
    droid.update();
}

}
```

FIG 1

[image]

FIG 2

[image]

FIG 3

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically it is you want help with?  Is it the app layout, the drag-and-drop, something specific to SurfaceView, the touch handling, ...?

Comment: How can I make my SurfaceView same as my layout(FIG 1 layout).

Comment: SurfaceView is a completely separate layer that sits behind all of the View elements.  It can be hard to work with for that reason.  If you're targeting API 14 or later, you can use a TextureView instead.

Comment: oh. Thanks a lot. I will try using TextureView.

Comment: @fadden: Can you please give me a sample on TextureView by which I can move my objects.

Comment: Do you still need this question?  Looks like you restated it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840201/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-other-applications-in-custom-launcer-android-progra

Comment: Yes. I need this functionality from API level 8 or 10, but textureview supports from API level 11. Please suggest me. I need this very badly.